# Deploying a Website with secret console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

Would it impact performance to leave console.log() in a deployed website ?

I have an idea of adding a secret code in the website that would turn on an off developer mode.

The code would be called if a DevMode password is passed to an input search bar, that other wise would just perform as a regular user input

So during a deployed session you can do:

```
if (DevMode===true){
console.log("bad code")
}
```

Is this a good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's will not impact performance, but let an dev access can compromise the security of your site